# How to use fetch in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, fetch

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        #button {
            width: 250px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-size: 32px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <button id="button" type="button" onclick="OnClick()">Show Data</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        function OnClick() {
            fetch('./Data.json')
                .then(res => res.json)
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                })
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

I try to make a function that data will show out when I click the button, but the console respond" *f json() {  [native code]   }*. How to fix this error

Comment: You aren't actually calling the function.... it needs to be `res.json()`

Comment: Your HTML is thoroughly invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute [`res.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json), as it's a function.

```
function OnClick() {
  fetch('./Data.json')
    .then(res => res.json()) // executing res.json
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
}
```

Comment: The HTML is thoroughly invalid.